# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null login.php:38

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using webstera cpanel for host my web application and here is my code and i'm using session  for log in

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in /home/buddhika/public_html/login.php:38 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in /home/buddhika/public_html/login.php on line 38

```
<?php
@ob_start();
session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <?php
include_once('php/db-connect.php');

$error = "";
$msg   = "";

if (isset($_SESSION["isLoggedIn"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

global $sql;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


    $sql    = "SELECT fname, password FROM login";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if (($_POST["username"] == $row["fname"]) && (($_POST["pass"]) == $row["password"])) {
                header("Location: index.php");
                $_SESSION["isLoggedIn"] = true;
                $_SESSION["username"]   = $row["fname"];
                $_SESSION["image"]      = $row["adimage"];

                //alert();
                $msg = "login success.";


            } else {
                $error = "Enter a valid username/password !!!";
            }

        }

    }
}
```

db connection class

```
<?php
class Db {
    // The database connection
    protected static $connection;

    /**
     * Connect to the database
     * 
     * @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
     */





    public function connect() {    
        // Try and connect to the database
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
            // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
            $config = parse_ini_file('./config.ini'); 
            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        }

        // If connection was not successful, handle the error
        if(self::$connection === false) {
            // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
            return false;
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }
public function query($query) {
    // Connect to the database
    $connection = $this -> connect();

    // Query the database
    $result = $connection -> query($query);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that the connection to the database is successful? Any suppressed error messages?

Comment: why is the question tagged as javascript with no code to support it?

Comment: basically, your query failed and is most likely the connection; show us what's in there including the HTML/form for this.

Comment: public function connect() {    
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
     
            $config = parse_ini_file('./config.ini'); 
            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        }

        // If connection was not successful, handle the error
        if(self::$connection === false) {
            // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
            return false;
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }

Comment: here is my db connection

Comment: *"public function connect()..."* - well that implies the use of a class. Your question needs to be updated in order to hold the complete code.

Comment: `$conn` != `$connection`.

Comment: it didnt work please help me

Answer (score 0):

"non-object" means that the variable (`$conn`) doesn't refer to an object. Did you assign it to your database class (e.g., `$conn = new databaseClass()`;, or whatever the class you're using is named)?

Comment: yes i include db class to the login.php